# SpringBoot not loading controllers which are generated using OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi-generator

I am generating code using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. The code is getting generated succesfully. But the spring boot is not loading the generated code in the context. I am not sure why, because I have done following things.

Below is my configuration of plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/spec/SchoolAPIs.v1.yaml</inputSpec>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/server</output>
                <language>spring</language>
                <apiPackage>com.school.rest.controllers</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.school.rest.generated.dtos</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <configOptions>
                    <java8>false</java8>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Below is my main class where I have specified the configuration:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, scanBasePackages = { "com.school.rest"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.school.rest.repository")
@Slf4j
public class SchoolAPIApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SchoolAPIApplication.class)
                .registerShutdownHook(true).run(args);
        PlansApiController plansApiController = context.getBean(PlansApiController.class);
        log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}", plansApiController);
    }

}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here, been struggling with this for almost 2 days. Can't figure out what is missing.

Please let me know if you have any solutions available.

Update: This call results in following error>

```
log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}", plansApiController);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type...
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your generated packages are not being scanned at startup.
I have tried to recreate your problem and solution here https://github.com/tinashehondo/notifications-api

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/api</output>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <modelPackage>uk.co.tinashehondo.notifications.rest.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>uk.co.tinashehondo.notifications.rest.api</apiPackage>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>false</java8>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
     scanBasePackages = { "uk.co.tinashehondo.notifications.rest"})
 public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new        SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
            .registerShutdownHook(true).run(args);
    NotificationApi notificationApiController =    context.getBean(NotificationApi.class);
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}"+notificationApiController); //forgive sys.out here
}
```

}

Output

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     {}uk.co.tinashehondo.notifications.rest.api.NotificationApiController@7b948f3e
```

Comment: My question is bit different, I am able to generate the controllers but not able to detect them in the context.

Comment: Yes, just simply generating the controller will not inject them into the context, you still need to register them, those generated controller classes do don't have any annotation that allows scanning into the application context, you still have to "implement" those generated interfaces, just that one like the snippet I have put there, just that snippet and scanning that then you will be able to detect them in the application context,

Comment: Those are already implemented classes, you can generate them with "delegatePattern"true - once you do this you have to only provide implementation of delegates, you would have a "PlansApi" (interface) and "PlansApiController" (Implementation of the interface) as part of generated code.

Comment: Hi @BilboBaggins, I am also facing the same issue. My controllers are generated but spring is not able to add them in the context. Did you find any fix for this? I'll update you in case if I find the fix.

Comment: @BilboBaggins , I have created a small project to show you what I meant, have a look at this [https://github.com/tinashehondo/notifications-api]

Comment: @JigarThakkar have a look 
I have tried to recreate your problem and solution here https://github.com/tinashehondo/notifications-api

Comment: Sure, let me have a look, thank you for giving your time to solve my problem.

Comment: Guys. Having quite the same problem, but: 1) My controllers API interfaces is working and responding. But swagger v3 couldn't see description from generated (v2) interfaces. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for me the answer goes like this,

I am facing the issue because of the lower `spring-boot` version, which was not supporting reading from the interfaces that are generated. And because of that reason, the code generator was generating code with Interfaces annotated with all the documentation but was not being read by the spring and added to context.

Upgrade my spring version from `2.0.0` to `2.1.4` and things are fixed. 
Posting here for others reference.